# Boolean masking a list of different lengths within each individual row

Tags: python, pandas, boolean, iteration

I have the following dataframe:

```python
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'tags': [
        [{'id': 1401}, {'id': 1801}],
        [{'id': 502}, {'id': 703}, {'id': 1801}],
        [{'id': 1801}]
    ]
})
```

I am only interested in the `'id': 1801` value in the `'tags'` column and would like to create a new column which contains `True` if `'id': 1801` is present or `False` if it is not.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can `explode` the `tags` column then using `str` accesor get the value of `id` and compare it with `1801` to create a boolean mask followed by `any` on `level=0` to reduce:

```
df['flag'] = df['tags'].explode().str['id'].eq(1801).any(level=0)
```

If dataframe is big and performance needs to be considred then we can use `list comprehension` which will outperform all of the available pandas based solution

```
df['flags'] = [any(d['id'] == 1801 for d in l) for l in df['tags']]
```

---

```
                                       tags  flag
0              [{'id': 1401}, {'id': 1801}]  True
1  [{'id': 502}, {'id': 703}, {'id': 1801}]  True
2                            [{'id': 1801}]  True
```

Answer (score 0):

Use lambda function with `any` if performance is important with `get` for test also if `id` missing:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'tags': [
        [{'id': 1401}, {'id': 1801}],
        [{'id': 502}, {'id': 703}, {'id': 1801}],
        [{'id': 1}]
    ]
})

df['new'] = df['tags'].apply(lambda x: any(y.get('id') == 1801 for y in x))
print (df)
                                       tags    new
0              [{'id': 1401}, {'id': 1801}]   True
1  [{'id': 502}, {'id': 703}, {'id': 1801}]   True
2                               [{'id': 1}]  False
```

---

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)

In [275]: %timeit df['tags'].explode().str['id'].eq(1801).any(level=0)
8.09 ms ± 265 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [276]: %timeit df['tags'].apply(lambda x: any(y.get('id') == 1801 for y in x))
2.64 ms ± 6.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

If always `id` exist per `tags`:

```
In [283]: %timeit [any(d['id'] == 1801 for d in l) for l in df['tags']]
2.44 ms ± 215 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```